# Cypress test logs in Team City are too verbose

Tags: teamcity, cypress

We are running Cypress tests in Team City and the output of the tests is crazy verbose. When I run the tests on the agent machine directly I don't see such verbose logging so it might be because of Team City.

Small sample (there are thousands of these):

```
cypress:https-proxy Making intercepted connection to 60378
cypress:server:server Got UPGRADE request from /__socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
cypress:server:timers queuing timer id 5 after 85000 ms
cypress:server:timers child received timer id 5
cypress:server:socket socket connected
cypress:server:timers clearing timer id 5 from queue { '3': { args: [], ms: 30000, cb: [Function: timeoutTimeout] }, '5': { args: [], ms: 85000, cb: [Function] } }
cypress:server:timers queuing timer id 6 after 85000 ms
cypress:server:timers child received timer id 6
cypress:server:timers clearing timer id 6 from queue { '3': { args: [], ms: 30000, cb: [Function: timeoutTimeout] }, '6': { args: [], ms: 85000, cb: [Function] } }
cypress:server:timers queuing timer id 7 after 85000 ms
cypress:server:timers queuing timer id 8 after 1000 ms
cypress:server:timers clearing timer id 8 from queue { '3': { args: [], ms: 30000, cb: [Function: timeoutTimeout] }, '7': { args: [], ms: 85000, cb: [Function] }, '8': { args: [], ms: 1000, cb: [Function: timeoutTimeout] } }
cypress:server:timers child received timer id 7
cypress:server:timers child received timer id 8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `@cypress/mocha-teamcity-reporter` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/mocha-teamcity-reporter ?

Comment: I tried using that by running Cypress like this: `cypress run --reporter teamcity` like they explain here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-reporter-lt-reporter-gt but I get the same issue.

I didn't install any npm package because of what the Cypress docs say that the teamcity reporter is included with Cypress and you don't need to install anything. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters.html#Custom-Reporters

Comment: I also just tried `cypress run --reporter mocha-teamcity-reporter` for good measure and I am getting an error that it can't find that reporter. But from what I gather from the docs I really only need to do `cypress run --reporter teamcity`, but there is a bit of conflicting information in the docs because further down on the custom reporters page it mentions having to install mocha. That seems strange to me

Comment: I see that `cypress run --reporter teamcity` is causing the Cypress tests to show up in the test tab, so that's good. But the build log output is still bonkers. At least we can see a summary of failed tests in the test tab though

Answer (score 0):

Those are Cypress' own [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) messages - they are only logged in case the `DEBUG` environment variable is set to a matching pattern, i.e. `*` or `cypress:*`. They are not related to the teamcity logger.

Either override the `env.DEBUG` Build Parameter in your Build Configuration and set it to an empty string, or (in case there's something else in your build that needs it to be set to `*`) *unset* it just at the launch inside your build step, like

```
env -u DEBUG npm run cypress  -- --reporter teamcity
```